# spring-security-facebook, s2-init-facebook not generating the Default Dao

Tags: facebook, grails, spring-security

I have installed spring-security-facebook to a test grail application. This was done after installing spring-security-core and running s2-quickstart.

I am just a novice and was trying to integrate the facebook login button into my test app. But, the problem is that when I run s2-init-facebook the plugin is not generating the default Dao as it was told in the documentation in http://grails.org/plugin/spring-security-facebook

> Use your own authentication dao
>
> Plugin generates an Dao, after calling s2-init-facebook@, and put it
>   into your @conf/spring/resources.groovy and @Config.groovy@. Actually
>   it's an 'dumb' dao implementations, you have to rewrite it to follow
>   your data structures:

The shortened tree output of my app directory is given below:

```
.
├── application.properties
├── grails-app
│   ├── conf
│   │   ├── ApplicationResources.groovy
│   │   ├── BootStrap.groovy
│   │   ├── BuildConfig.groovy
│   │   ├── Config.groovy
│   │   ├── DataSource.groovy
│   │   ├── hibernate
│   │   ├── spring
│   │   │   └── resources.groovy
│   │   └── UrlMappings.groovy
│   ├── controllers
│   │   ├── LoginController.groovy
│   │   └── LogoutController.groovy
│   ├── domain
│   │   └── com
│   │       └── fbtest
│   │           └── webapp
│   │               └── auth
│   │                   ├── FacebookUser.groovy
│   │                   ├── SecRole.groovy
│   │                   ├── SecUser.groovy
│   │                   └── SecUserSecRole.groovy
│   ├── i18n
│   │   ├── ...
│   ├── services
│   ├── taglib
│   ├── utils
│   └── views
│       ├── error.gsp
│       ├── index.gsp
│       ├── layouts
│       │   └── main.gsp
│       └── login
│           ├── auth.gsp
│           └── denied.gsp
├── lib
├── scripts
├── src
│   ├── groovy
│   └── java
├── test
│   ├── integration
│   └── unit
└── web-app
    ├── ...
```

resource.groovy file is also empty.

```
// Place your Spring DSL code here
beans = {
}
```

Please, help me in understanding if I am doing any thing wrong.

I am using Grails version: 2.0.4 and spring-security-facebook's version is 0.8.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Oh, it should be removed from documentation. For last versions it's not necessary to have own DAO, now it have default very flexible dao. And now it's not generated during install. Try to run your app, it should works, if everything is configured correctly.

You can still use own DAO, if you have implemented it by yourself. But for versions since 0.7 nearly everything can be extending with optional `FacebookAuthService`, that you can implement if you wish (it's described in documentation as well).

Comment: Thanks @Igor. The code is working fine. Just was a bit confused about that and I kept on thinking that I was doing something wrong.